# laravel 5.1 : how can i update one row only with where clause?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want update a row with only where clause. 
I don't have row id, only i have 2 where clause. 
Is it possible? 
(with eloquent)

```
->where("x",1) ->where("y"=2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using Active Record, you should never perform an update directly in the database. First pull the record from the database, then update it:

```php
Model::where(['x' => 1, 'y' => 2])->first()->update([...]);
```

If you instead do the update directly in the database, none of the ORM functionality will trigger (such as firing events or touching parents).

Answer (score 3):

Update all rows, which correspond conditions:

```
Model::where("x",1)->where("y",2)->update(array('key' => 'new_value', ...));
```

First row, which corresponds conditions:

```
Model::where("x",1)->where("y",2)->first()->update(array('key' => 'new_value', ...));
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternativly, to update table by one row at a time, method take(rows_count) can be used. 
Example:

```
Model::query()->where(['x' => 1, 'y' => 2])
->take(1)->update(['x' => 4, 'y' => 5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just fetch the row and then update it as usual.

```
SomeModel::where('somecondition', 'somevalue')
         ->where('someothercondition', 'someothervalue')
         ->first()
         ->update(['somecolumn' => 'somenewvalue']);
```